# Firebase transaction returns ArrayList handling

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to check if a child already has a value or not, if not then increment a child value and add an array of data inside the child. ex:

[image: current state]

and expect the code will add second child "2":

[image: expected result]

to do this I use doTransaction to check if there are any values within history/userId value,

```
Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = df.format(c);
PlanHistory planHistory = new PlanHistory(formattedDate, plan.getPlan_key(), plan.getPlan_name(), plan.getLevel_name(), plan.getType_name(), plan.getPersonal_trainer_id(), plan.getUri());
mDatabase.child("history").child(user.getUid()).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
        long value = 0;
        if(mutableData.getValue() != null) {
            String numQuestions = (String) mutableData.getValue();
            value = Long.parseLong(numQuestions, 16);
        }
        value++;
        String incHex = Long.toHexString(value);
        mutableData.setValue(incHex);
        mutableData.child(incHex).setValue(planHistory);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, boolean committed, @Nullable DataSnapshot currentData) {

    }
});
```

the problem lies when there's already a value inside the child node, it returns ArrayList and cannot be cast to String

[image: error stacktrace]

How can I fix the code so it can add the next node with incremented child name from previous one just like the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make this call:

```
String numQuestions = (String) mutableData.getValue();
```

You get the value of the `MutableData` object, which contains all data under `mDatabase.child("history").child(user.getUid())` from your database. So that is way more data than a single string. My guess is that you're looking for:

```
String numQuestions = (String) mutableData.getKey();
```

Comment: now when it already has a value, the key still returns null while it should returns 1

Comment: If the original problems/error is gone, that means this is a new problem. You might want to step through the code in a debugger to see why that happens, keeping in mind that it is normal for the `doTransaction` to be called with an empty snapshot initially even when there is data in the database.

Comment: ahh i see, okay i will ask a new question! thank you for your answer!