# Add increment childname to firebase and then add arrays to it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In addition to my previous question: [Firebase transaction returns ArrayList handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306100/firebase-transaction-returns-arraylist-handling/65308996?noredirect=1#comment115461809_65308996)

I still can't add a child node with incremental ID, I already tried using the solution in this post: [Android studio value increment in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477000/android-studio-value-increment-in-firebase;)

my best effort is this:

```
mDatabase.child("history").child(user.getUid()).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
      Log.i("HISTORY", "List length: "+ mutableData.getKey());
      long value = 0;
      if(mutableData.getKey() != null) {
            String numRecords = (String) mutableData.getKey();
            value = Long.parseLong(numRecords, 16);
      }
      value++;
      incHex = Long.toHexString(value);
      mutableData.setValue(incHex);
      return Transaction.success(mutableData);
  }
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, boolean committed, @Nullable DataSnapshot currentData) {
       Log.i("HISTORY", "List length: "+ currentData.getKey());
       mDatabase.child("history").child(user.getUid()).child(incHex).setValue(planHistory);
  }
});
```

but it just update the child ID 1 value, not adding a child ID 2 and add value to it.

How can I add incremental child ID and put arrays on it?

**EDIT:**
this is the JSON tree:

```
"history" : {
"CgLSsYAk2Tel8A8FSPLA5rBH8ZG2" : [ null, {
  "date" : "16-Dec-2020",
  "level_name" : "Body Builder",
  "personal_trainer_id" : "aHb1vJ8JmBTuO7TArx4ehVeDbJJ2",
  "plan_key" : "Plan6",
  "plan_name" : "Perfect Abdominal Muscles ",
  "type_name" : "Abs",
  "uri" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zahfit-s-mobile-app.appspot.com/o/exercise_plan%2Fmotiontoburn.jpg?alt=media&token=bd5ebb02-f9fb-48bf-880f-a1724c5b38ee"
} ]
 },
```

Comment: Please include the JSON at `/history/$uid` in your question (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: i already edit it @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: One of the things that's immediately visible in your JSON is the `null` value in the array, which Firebase generates when the JSON data looks like an array. For this and many other reasons it is recommended to use Firebase's built-in `push()` keys, instead of trying to generated sequential IDs yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I think I use push() instead of using transaction@FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a transaction at a location, you get all data at that location, and have to tell the database all data that needs to exist at the location after the write operation.

Since you read from `/history/$uid`, you get all data from that location, and need to make sure the `MutableData` you return contains all data for `/history/$uid` too. By calling `mutableData.setValue(incHex)`, you're telling the database to replace whatever now exists at `/history/$uid` with the new incremented value.

More likely you'll want to do something like:

```
mutableData.child(incHex).setValue("the value or `Map` for the new location");
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Frank van Puffelen's advice, instead of using Transaction, I use Firebase built-in push() function.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String formattedDate = df.format(c);
    mDatabase.child("history").child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(new PlanHistory(formattedDate, plan.getPlan_key(), plan.getPlan_name(), plan.getLevel_name(), plan.getType_name(), plan.getPersonal_trainer_id(), plan.getUri()));
}
```

although it's not incremented value but generated push key instead, it still fulfills my needs.

json tree using push():

```
"history" : {
"CgLSsYAk2Tel8A8FSPLA5rBH8ZG2" : {
  "-MOdgaP_SBTQ2xXmn6au" : {
    "date" : "16-Dec-2020",
    "level_name" : "Easy",
    "personal_trainer_id" : "aHb1vJ8JmBTuO7TArx4ehVeDbJJ2",
    "plan_key" : "Plan3",
    "plan_name" : "Abs Fat Reduction",
    "type_name" : "Abs",
    "uri" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zahfit-s-mobile-app.appspot.com/o/exercise_plan%2Fmotiontoburn.jpg?alt=media&token=bd5ebb02-f9fb-48bf-880f-a1724c5b38ee"
  },
  "-MOdgbpKBfFxjpPVR2JD" : {
    "date" : "16-Dec-2020",
    "level_name" : "Medium",
    "personal_trainer_id" : "aHb1vJ8JmBTuO7TArx4ehVeDbJJ2",
    "plan_key" : "Plan9",
    "plan_name" : "Form the Abdominal Muscle",
    "type_name" : "Abs",
    "uri" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zahfit-s-mobile-app.appspot.com/o/exercise_plan%2Fmotiontoburn.jpg?alt=media&token=bd5ebb02-f9fb-48bf-880f-a1724c5b38ee"
  },
  "-MOdgmYMUIIZo0hasON_" : {
    "date" : "16-Dec-2020",
    "level_name" : "Body Builder",
    "personal_trainer_id" : "aHb1vJ8JmBTuO7TArx4ehVeDbJJ2",
    "plan_key" : "Plan4",
    "plan_name" : "Hercules Excercise",
    "type_name" : "Full body",
    "uri" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zahfit-s-mobile-app.appspot.com/o/exercise_plan%2Fmotiontoburn.jpg?alt=media&token=bd5ebb02-f9fb-48bf-880f-a1724c5b38ee"
  }
}
```

},